# Not able to update profile pic in MFSideMenu

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, sdwebimage, image-caching

I am trying to update my profile picture on side menu (MFSideMenu) and as soon as I update profile picture over the web server, I want to set it on my iOS app. URL of the image being the same, I am unable to upgrade it. I guess the problem is that every time I change image, image url being the same is loaded from the cache memory so it doesn't change. Is there any way to download changed image as when it changes without the need to change imageUrl?

In response I always get

```
imageUrl :"user_image" = "profile/local/images/user_id/myimage";
```

Accordingly I update my model and fetch information from model as I open the side menu.

```
`func menuAction(){ 
        self.getUserDetails()        
 }

func getUserDetails()  {
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: self)
self.menuContainerViewController.toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion(nil)
}`
```

Comment: use NSNotificationCentre

Comment: I have used NSNotification centre already but still it doesn't  change image

Comment: image updated on web server?

Comment: yes, image updated on web server but not updating on side menu even after firing notification.

Comment: please share the code of notification function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I fixed the issue by firing notification from the app delegate and updating side menu so that whenever application will open , data will be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a quick fix. But this is not the best way.

Add different query parameters to the url when you going to set(download) the image.

For eg:
If your image url is http://www.yourserver.com/images/my_image.png then change it to http://www.yourserver.com/images/my_image.png**?any_name=timestamp**

Comment: I have tried adding time_stamp but still not able to update image.
'NSString *currentTimeStamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
NSString *user_profilePic = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?time=%@",[json valueForKeyPath:@"userDetails.user_image"],currentTimeStamp];'

Comment: I fixed the issue by firing notification from the app delegate and updating side menu so that whenever application will open , data will be refreshed.